# React: TypeError: Cannot read property 'newValue' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following in `componentDidMount`

```
componentDidMount() {
    const company = this.props.location.state.company;
    const financials = this.props.location.state.financials;

    let { values } = this.state;

    values = EDITABLES.map((data) => { //EDITABLES is a const imported array
     return {
      id: data.id,
      name: data.name,
      value: financials[data.id]
      newValue: "",
     };
    });

  this.setState({
    values,
  });
}
```

However, if I console.log the `values` at the time of render, the first console log shows it as undefined, but the next one shows it as defined. I am also able to `map` the `values` in my render method without any problem.

```
render() {
    const {
      company,
      financials,
      values,
    } = this.state;

    console.log(values, "check")
```

My problem is that in my render method, I call a function `{this.calculate(financial.id)}`

```
 calculate(financial) {
    const { financials, values } = this.state;
    console.log(values, "values"); 
    let numerator;
    if (financial === "tev_profit") { //this line is okay
      let tev = values.find(o => o.id === "total_value");
      console.log(tev, "here"); 
      numerator = tev.newValue; //this line is causing error.
```

From the console log it seems as if `tev` is sometimes defined but other times not. I'm not sure where I'm going wrong because I also added this to my code but still facing the same typeError:

```
this.calculate = this.calculate.bind(this);
```

Update:
I have tried adding `if(values)` to my `calculate` function before I go into any other if block, but getting the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

[Array.prototype.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) can return `undefined` if element isn't found.

> The `find()` method returns the value of the first element in the
> provided array that satisfies the provided testing function. If no
> values satisfy the testing function, `undefined` is returned.

## Solution

Check for valid `tev` object before accessing properties

```
if (financial === "tev_over_ltm_gross_profit") {
  const tev = values.find(o => o.id === "total_enterprise_value");
  if (tev) {
    // tev exists
    numerator = tev.newValue;
  }
```